# Using a tupperware as outdoor case could mean an static electricity problem?

Tags: case

I mounted a r-pi with a camera module and want to set it outdoors, getting rain, sun and wind.

This is a prototype and later I will try to find a more professional solution, but so far I want to set it out and begin tests, so I used a plastic tupperware.

My question is, is this a danger and could the board get damaged by static electricty? Appart for the usual earthing before manipulating the board, should I have some extra precautions?

Thanks

Comment: Good question. There is a forum dedicated to electrical engineering where you will likely get more accurate answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static electricity is just that. It's static. Think about it, how could static electricity i.e. a whole bunch of electrons build up on a box just sitting there? It doesn't. Static is normally a problem when someone walks across a synthetic carpet and builds up a charge on himself. Then you touch something like your box and discharge your excess electrons into the box. How likely is that to happen? Not likely. Go ahead, install your gear in the box and install the box. If you need to touch the box again later touch the pole or something grounded before you touch the Project inside the box.
Regards Bob

Comment: A good answer in principle, and your recommendation to touch something else before handling is a good one. Some materials, including some plastics, actually can build up a charge from just sitting outside in the wind, under the right dry/dusty conditions. If the built up discharges through the board, on the way from the plastic container to you as you pick it up, it could potentially cause some damage, but generally speaking, the act of opening the lid and general handling would probably mitigate most of the risk of this occurring.

Comment: @JohnT that's why I asked, if there was a possibilty than the box took to much electricty from wind, but a good practice of course is to isolate my board from plastic inside and to earth myself after opening box

Answer (score -1):

If it's connected to power, rather than running off a battery, it's grounded, and static build-up shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: No, it likely isn't. Most AC/DC adapters are not grounded but galvanically isolated from mains.

Comment: The raspberry pi is very unlikely to be grounded if it’s running off a double insulated mains power adaptor, as most DC mains adaptors are. The answer is wrong and should be removed.